# Google translate API v2 encoding Chinese character and guide

Tags: php, html, curl, google-api, microsoft-translator

*Solution below as answer*

```
$test = "橘色,灰色,深蓝,绿色";
```

$completeColours also contains the same text, just that the texts are joint by a for loop character by character to form the text like $test.

I copy pasted $test's charcters manually. The weird problem here is, when I pass $test into the url below , it works! BUT WHEN I put $completeColours instead of $test, it doesn't work :O

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?To=%27'.$to.'%27&From=%27'.$from.'%27&Text=%27'.$test.'%27');
```

When i echo $test i just created it returns `æ©˜è‰²,ç°è‰²,æ·±è“,ç»¿è‰²`
When i echo $completeColours it returns `橘色,灰色,深蓝,绿色`

Comment: how about `urlencode()` / `urldecode()` ?

Comment: Hi @CORRUPT Yap i used urlencode() it worked fine with google, not for microsoft.

Comment: `iconv()` + `urlencode()` or `utf8_encode()` + `urlencode()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue, maybe try using the unicode? `&#27224;,&#33394;,&#28784;&#33394;,&#28145;,&#34013;,&#32511;&#33394;`
results in
橘,色,灰色,深蓝,绿,色

Answer (score 1):

use `rawurlencode($completeColours)` instead.

Comment: can you print $completeColours, and check the value with $test?

Answer (score 1):

Use google Translator API v2, it understands urlencode in chinese, Microsoft's translate api doesn't.

I will just share this code here, Google Translator API v2 using CURL in PHP

```
    $text = urlencode($completeColours);
$from = 'zh-CHS';
$to = 'en';

$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=API_KEY_HERE&source=zh-CN&target=en&q='.$text.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$newresult = json_decode($result,true);
$student_id = $newresult['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];

echo $student_id;
```

If you are a first time user of google api, remember to set the quota in google API , your own set of quota, dont use the default. For some reason if you dont customize your own quota , it will return you a error Reached Max Limit.